# Python urllib.request and urllib.error usage

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a small amount of Python code that uses urllib.request and urllib.error to check the status of a URL. On an error this should then trigger an SNS publish to topic.

```
import boto3
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from os import environ

region = 'eu-west-2'

def get_status_code(url, topic):
    try:
        connection = urlopen(url, timeout=10)
        status = connection.getcode()
        print('%s Status is %s' % (url, status))
        connection.close()
    except HTTPError as err:
        status = err.getcode()
        print('%s: Status is unreachable - %s' % (url, status))
        sns_client = boto3.client('sns', region_name=region)
        message = sns_client.publish(TopicArn=topic,
                                     Message='%s is unreachable - HTTP error code is: %s' % (url, status)
                                     )
        print("Publish to SNS, Lambda update triggered: {}".format(message))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dns = environ['dns']
    sns_topic = environ['sns_topic_arn']

    get_status_code(dns, sns_topic)
```

As part of testing this I have experienced different levels of success. If I keep the timeout in urlopen it fails to trigger the except handler but does dump a failure. If setting a timeout limit and it is hit is considered an error then why doesn't it trigger the exception handler?

```
timed out: timeout
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function1.py", line 27, in lambda_handler
    get_status_code(elb_dns, sns_topic)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function1.py", line 10, in get_status_code
    connection = urlopen(url, timeout=10)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1377, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1352, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1379, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 311, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 272, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

If I remove the timeout from urlopen the job times out after 3mins and triggers the except handler and then finishes successfully (I know if it hasn't worked after 10s its not going to).

A second unexpected error is also appearing if I use a HTTPS URL. It also fails to trigger the exception handler.

```
<urlopen error timed out>: URLError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function1.py", line 24, in lambda_handler
    get_status_code(elb_dns, sns_topic)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function1.py", line 8, in get_status_code
    connection = urlopen(url, timeout=10)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1392, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I was adding the errors that were output I noticed that they did not write to HTTPError (I expected the timeout to at least if the default timeout does???) that the exception handler is expecting:

```
import boto3
import socket
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from os import environ

region = 'eu-west-2'

def get_status_code(url, topic):
    try:
        connection = urlopen(url, timeout=10)
        status = connection.getcode()
        print('%s Status is %s' % (url, status))
        connection.close()
    except (socket.timeout, URLError, HTTPError) as err:
        status = err
        print('%s: Status is unreachable - %s' % (url, status))
        sns_client = boto3.client('sns', region_name=region)
        message = sns_client.publish(TopicArn=topic,
                                     Message='%s is unreachable - HTTP error code is: %s' % (url, status)
                                     )
        print("Publish to SNS, Lambda update triggered: {}".format(message))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dns = environ['dns']
    sns_topic = environ['sns_topic_arn']

    get_status_code(dns, sns_topic)
```

So I added the new errors to the exception handler and they are now being captured and handled. It does break my "HTTP error code is" since I now just get the error message but it is working better than before.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that this error: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error timed out> is indicative of an AWS Lambda function that was unable to communicate with the URL (and the SNS endpoint but not by this error) so not a HTTP error. Check that security groups are appropriate as well as VPC and less so subnets.